# How to add multiple containers in Azure Storage Container task in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-container-instances

I want to add multiple containers to Container Name section in Azure Storage container task in Azure Devops.

I want to create 5 containers and provide list of container name.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly on the task, but this is doable on [Agent job level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-job-configuration).

[image]

Variable `containersList` should have comma separated list `one,two,three,four` and in `Create blob` task you refer to it as `$(containersList)`

However, in this way you will get `Deploy json file` run many times. If this is not what you need, please consider moving `Create blob containers` into separate job.

ANother option is to use [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) and [`az storage container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_container_create) where you can just create foreach loop and call CLI command.

Comment: Create blob containers task is not available.  Using Azure CLI task, how can I get azure context, when service connection is created. Without Client Id & Client secret is it possible to connect to azure storage account?